# Grouping of states, cities into countries in R

Tags: r

In R, I ran a code to get a data frame of two columns which has cities, countries and the corresponding numbers .

I ran `summary()` on the column and converted the result to a data frame.

I am trying to group together, all the states into one country. For example in the below output, I would like to group together all US states, cities into one Country "United States" . Can i use `grep()` to find patterns and then use some package to group together? Please advise a way to do this.

```
location<-summary(pind$userLocation)
location<-as.data.frame(location)
location
```

Data:

```
                     location
                       271286
null                    58145
Texas                    1027
United States             900
USA                       866
Paris                     755
California                590
Canada                    535
Florida                   438
New York                  392
Australia                 379
London                    375
Ohio                      373
Michigan                  354
Chicago, IL               335
Los Angeles, CA           323
Chicago                   299
Colorado                  275
New York, NY              275
North Carolina            271
Minnesota                 259
Seattle, WA               254
Los Angeles               249
Indiana                   247
Virginia                  244
Wisconsin                 231
Arizona                   224
Atlanta, GA               221
Dallas, TX                220
Oregon                    218
Georgia                   204
Houston, TX               200
Oklahoma                  200
Utah                      198
Austin, TX                190
Pennsylvania              189
Illinois                  187
San Diego, CA             184
Tennessee                 182
UK                        182
Missouri                  181
Kentucky                  173
San Francisco, CA         172
Louisiana                 167
NYC                       167
Alabama                   163
Nashville, TN             157
Iowa                      149
Boston, MA                148
Kansas                    145
Southern California       144
Denver, CO                142
New Jersey                140
Sydney, Australia         138
South Carolina            134
Washington, DC            133
Maryland                  128
Arkansas                  127
Portland, OR              126
Phoenix, AZ               125
Atlanta                   124
London, UK                124
Melbourne, Australia      123
Ontario, Canada           121
Seattle                   121
Washington                121
Las Vegas, NV             116
New Zealand               116
United Kingdom            116
Brooklyn, NY              115
CA                        110
Minneapolis, MN           109
Houston, Texas            105
NC                        104
New York City             103
Toronto                   103
Austin, Texas             101
Charlotte, NC             101
South Africa              100
Pittsburgh, PA             98
San Francisco              98
Vancouver, BC              95
Germany                    94
Phoenix, Arizona           92
Barcelona                  89
Dallas, Texas              89
Portland, Oregon           89
England                    88
Idaho                      86
.                          83
San Diego                  83
West Virginia              83
Nevada                     82
The Netherlands            81
France                     79
Raleigh, NC                78
Kansas City, MO            76
Massachusetts              75
US                         75
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your data isn't that extensive, this can be done by hand pretty easily. I went through each record and identified which country it belongs to, and added a new column with the result. Once you have the country, you can use `aggregate()` to get the sum:

```
location <- data.frame(location=c(271286,58145,1027,900,866,755,590,535,438,392,379,375,373,354,335,323,299,275,275,271,259,254,249,247,244,231,224,221,220,218,204,200,200,198,190,189,187,184,182,182,181,173,172,167,167,163,157,149,148,145,144,142,140,138,134,133,128,127,126,125,124,124,123,121,121,121,116,116,116,115,110,109,105,104,103,103,101,101,100,98,98,95,94,92,89,89,89,88,86,83,83,83,82,81,79,78,76,75,75),row.names=c('','null','Texas','United States','USA','Paris','California','Canada','Florida','New York','Australia','London','Ohio','Michigan','Chicago, IL','Los Angeles, CA','Chicago','Colorado','New York, NY','North Carolina','Minnesota','Seattle, WA','Los Angeles','Indiana','Virginia','Wisconsin','Arizona','Atlanta, GA','Dallas, TX','Oregon','Georgia','Houston, TX','Oklahoma','Utah','Austin, TX','Pennsylvania','Illinois','San Diego, CA','Tennessee','UK','Missouri','Kentucky','San Francisco, CA','Louisiana','NYC','Alabama','Nashville, TN','Iowa','Boston, MA','Kansas','Southern California','Denver, CO','New Jersey','Sydney, Australia','South Carolina','Washington, DC','Maryland','Arkansas','Portland, OR','Phoenix, AZ','Atlanta','London, UK','Melbourne, Australia','Ontario, Canada','Seattle','Washington','Las Vegas, NV','New Zealand','United Kingdom','Brooklyn, NY','CA','Minneapolis, MN','Houston, Texas','NC','New York City','Toronto','Austin, Texas','Charlotte, NC','South Africa','Pittsburgh, PA','San Francisco','Vancouver, BC','Germany','Phoenix, Arizona','Barcelona','Dallas, Texas','Portland, Oregon','England','Idaho','.','San Diego','West Virginia','Nevada','The Netherlands','France','Raleigh, NC','Kansas City, MO','Massachusetts','US'));
location$country <- factor(c(NA,NA,'United States','United States','United States','France','United States','Canada','United States','United States','Australia','United Kingdom','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United Kingdom','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','Australia','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United States','United Kingdom','Australia','Canada','United States','United States','United States','New Zealand','United Kingdom','United States','Canada','United States','United States','United States','United States','Canada','United States','United States','South Africa','United States','United States','Canada','Germany','United States','Spain','United States','United States','United Kingdom','United States',NA,'United States','United States','United States','Netherlands','France','United States','United States','United States','United States'));
aggregate(location~country,location,sum);
##           country location
## 1       Australia      640
## 2          Canada      964
## 3          France      834
## 4         Germany       94
## 5     Netherlands       81
## 6     New Zealand      116
## 7    South Africa      100
## 8           Spain       89
## 9  United Kingdom      885
## 10  United States    15964
```

I used NA where the country could not be determined from the location name alone; I'm referring to the three records with names `''`, `'null'`, and `'.'`. Because `aggregate()` ignores records with group values of NA, those records are not included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I understand the question but I'll give it a shot.

So you want to identify for each location string what country it belongs to and then group them together and do an operation based on the country groups?

If that is the case then what comes to mind is using the geocoding function from ggmap that used the google maps API, this only makes sense if you aren't doing that many queries.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggmap)

MyGeoCode <- function(Location){
  return(geocode(Location,output = "more")$country)
}

location$country <- sapply(location$location,MyGeoCode)

 location <- location %>% group_by(country) %>% summarise(TotalPerCountry=sum(numbercolumn,na.rm = TRUE))
```

This example assumes you want to sum the number column for each country, for other operations follow in the same manner.

Comment: What I am trying to is, identify all the states in US, for example Michigan, Texax, NY, etc and I want group them under United States as the country. So all the US states along with the count in the above result, should be group under "United States" with the  individual state counts aggregated.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe of how you wish the end product to look like?

Comment: My output dataframe should look like below   ( United states count should be a combination of all US states , and their counts summed up), likewise for Canada. It should include counts of Toronto, british columbia etc.. and they should be grouped under Canada                                                                         



United States             1900

Canada                    1535

UK                        182

Australia                 123

Germany                    94

The Netherlands            81

France                     79

Comment: I want every country in the data frame. Its just that the individual states in the country should be grouped under the countries name and not explicitly.